# Path objects are abstract or not?

Tags: java, path, nio

Aren't Path object only refering to abstract paths?
From the following quote gotten from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#startsWith%28java.nio.file.Path%29):

> If the given path is associated with a different FileSystem to this
>   path then false is returned.

Does not seems so. If it was only abstract would not matter which filesystem would refer to.
Isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `Path` instances aren't inherently related to the underling file system path, the actual implementing class can be different. For example, you have `WindowsPath` (`WindowsFileSystem`) and `ZipPath` (`ZipFileSystem`). Although the path string itself might be the same, they are related to different [`FileSystem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html)s, so the method should return `false`.

`Path` is an interface. The implementation of `startsWith` however cares about the actual implementation type of the `Path` instance passed to it.

Comment: So basically it returns true only it it is the same path.. the name it's quite confusing as it appears to check only the beginning

Comment: @IndeedItIs It returns true if it is the same path from the same `FileSystem`. Say you had a path inside a zip file like `/usr/app/file.txt` and a file from the root of your file system like `/usr/app/file.txt`. Although the paths are represented by the same String, they are not in any way equal (or `startsWith` eachother).